# SOAP SignatureValue generate on PHP

Tags: php, soap, sign

**Hi all, I have next XML:**

```
<ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsa cor soap"
            xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
        <ds:Reference URI="#id-2">
            <ds:Transforms>
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                    <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="cor"
                        xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    </ds:Transform>
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                <ds:DigestValue>oGDoMATVcLIjqmglMqUJSkezEfM=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
            <ds:Reference URI="#TS-23">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsse wsa cor soap"
                            xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </ds:Transform>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                    <ds:DigestValue>4oZ/yS5H6z/sRpotlj3lcPzs5t0=</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
```

**Trying to calculate signature next:**

```
$this->privateKey = openssl_pkey_get_private($key, $passphrase);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml_signed_info);
$xml_signed_info = $dom->C14N();
openssl_sign($xml_signed_info, $signature, $this->privateKey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);
$signature = base64_encode($signature);
```

**Private key looks next:**

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Trying to add different name spaces to SignedInfo block. But signature always wrong - api can't accept my signature.

Maybe you have any idea? Or works with similar issue?
I need help :(

Comment: You're posting a private key online?

Comment: It was changed before posting :)